# Programs that use URN protocol

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, url, network-protocols, utility

Does there any Windows 10 program or handler to use URN protocol?
It's possible to write a script that handles the URN protocol and register it in the Windows registry. But is there a finished utility?

Comment: URN is not a protocol, just like URL or UUID aren't protocols. They're just identifiers.

Comment: @gronostaj, but where does they used? For example, if there is a search for a file or any abstract object by writing its UUID with `urn:uuid:` before

Comment: That depends completely on implementation. Just by looking at a URN you can't tell how to access the resource that it represents or what namespace that resource belongs to. The same URN could identify two different resources in two different namespaces. It's not a perfect metaphor, but URN is like a phone number. It's not very useful if you don't know the country code. Two people in different countries can have the same phone number but with different country codes in front of them. A phone number can be valid with one country's code, but not with another's.

Comment: Or to put it differently: URN identifies a particular resource in a namespace. Everyone can create their own namespace(s) and use whatever URNs they want. URN uniqueness is only guaranteed within a namespace.